# Docker: Is there a limit to the number of build-arg's you can have?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, docker-build

I'm using Azure pipelines and trying to build a docker image but getting stuck on this error:

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
```

I have over 20 --build-arg `ENV_VAL=$(ENV_VAL)` (example), and was thinking maybe its throwing that error because of the number of build args.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: To get more idea, can you paste the entire `docker build` command with complete error.

Comment: Did you make sure to provide a build context as the final argument? This error has come up before. Like @mchawre said, could you please share your actual command as well if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1,It can be caused by the missing of the `.` at the end of your docker command.

```
docker build -f MyDockerfile -t proj:myapp .
```

The `.` at the end specify the build context to be the current working directory.

2,If the build-args you passed has space in it. It can also cause above error. Please check if the `$(ENV_VAL)` you passed in the build-args has spaces in it. To avoid this. You can wrap the variables in quotes. See below:

```
 --build-arg ENV_VAL="$(ENV_VAL)"
```

3,Please also check the format of your docker command, if you copied and pasted your command. There might be some hidden formatting in your command that caused the error.

If you were using docker task in azure pipeline. you can select the Path to `Build context`. Select `**` to set the build context to the folder where the dockerfile resides.

[image]

Comment: Wrapping the build arg value in double quotes " worked.

Comment: @HarveyConnor That's great it fixed the issue. Could you accept above answer? since it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/cli/cli/command/image/build.go#L119), all options including `--build-arg` is treat as `options` not `arg`:

```
flags.Var(&options.buildArgs, "build-arg", "Set build-time variables")
```

So, for `docker build`, only one arg needed, it's `build context`, see [this](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/cli/cli/command/image/build.go#L111):

```
options.context = args[0]
```

And the error `"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.` comes from [here](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/cli/cli/required.go#L91), means you did not specify `build context`, not related to `--build-arg`.